# In ASP.NET MVC 4 user is being logged off randomly during ajax post request and forwarded to /Account/LogOff

Tags: ajax, authentication, asp.net-mvc-4

In MVC 4 I use ajax post to call a simple method

```
[HttpPost]
    public void Create(Task task)
    {
      if (ModelState.IsValid)
      {
      var userName = User.Identity.Name;
      task.Author = userName;
      db.Tasks.Add(task);
      db.SaveChanges();
      }
    }
```

Even before the method finishes (I used debugging) the web-server launches another process, executes LogOff method in AccountController and forwards the browser to /Account/LogOff url.
This is a simple project based on Internate template. Web.config includes basic setup for forms authentication. This happens ~70% of the cases. Looks like SimpleMembership provider senses danger and logs user out.

[Similar Case](http://forums.asp.net/t/1860856.aspx/1/10?Re%20MVC%203%20ASPNET%20Auth%20Almost%20Randomly%20Redirecting%20To%20Account%20LogOff)

Answer (score 0):

have you checked already your web.config file?

```
<configuration>
<system.web>     
    <authentication mode= "Forms">
        <forms name="MyLoginCookie" loginUrl="account/login" protection="[All/None/Encryption/Validation]" timeout="30" path="/” />
    </authentication>
</system.web>
```

Comment: I had a little more simple <authentication> section but I checked again with your section, it is the same - user is logged off during ajax request